# Left it late to net dramatic equaliser

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I don't understand the verb "left it", what does it mean? What does "it" refer to?

> At the death! ⏱
>
> Richarlison **left it** late to net a dramatic equaliser on our last
> trip to The Hawthorns! ⚽️

#WatfordFC | #GoalOfTheDay https://t.co/vgyWlVXF7D

Comment: Google the expression **to leave something late**

Comment: Presumably the equaliser was scored in the last few minutes of the match.

Comment: Could you te me what "left it" means here?

Comment: Did you do as Ronald suggested? I did, and I found [this definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/leave-something-too-late). In this case, he didn't leave it 'too late', just late (near the end of the match).

Answer (score 1):

"Left it late" is an idiomatic expression meaning that you have waited until the last moment to do something. In some contexts, it can imply procrastination, but crucially it doesn't usually mean that you have left it *too* late.

In the context of your example, a sporting match, it doesn't really suggest procrastination, or that any deliberate delaying took place. It is just a dramatic way of saying that the equalising goal was scored in the final moments of the game.

The word "it" in any context refers to something either previously mentioned, or tacitly understood. When using this phrase, 'it' could refer to the subject already being discussed, but in your example, the sentence goes on to state the thing that was left until late - the goal.

Comment: Does "leave" itself mean to score in this  context? "It" refers to "goal."

Comment: @Jembot It just means "to wait". We say "waited until last minute" as well as "left it until last minute".